# Trying to get a platform to fall after touching it for a total of 5 seconds in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, triggers, wait

I'm attempting to make a falling animation activate after my Player steps on a platform for a certain amount of time. I'm trying to do this in Unity with c#.

I've tried to use a coroutine to execute code over time but it does not seem to work in an on trigger enter method. I've also tried to use a bool and a timer variable to see if the player is touching for set amount of seconds.

```
IEnumerator OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player")
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
            myAnimationController.SetBool("FallWhenTouched", true);
            Debug.Log("It Worked");
            Debug.Log(other.gameObject.name);

            
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is that Unity code? If so, you may want to tag it as such

Comment: `yeild` isn't going to compile. Are you certain this code is being executed?

Comment: surely you set the timer to zero (or 5) in on triggerstay you add/remove some time, and when 0 or 5 trigger the fall?

Answer (score 0):

I would just use standard Invoke function with time delay.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Player")
    {
        Invoke(nameof(ActivateFall), 5.0f);
    }
}
private void ActivateFall() {
  myAnimationController.SetBool("FallWhenTouched", true);
}
```

Comment: I used your code but the platform just falls as soon as i start the game.  Stepping in the trigger zone doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to consider in your case is to prevent multiple calls for the drop. If  player jumps on the platform and then jumps again, it would trigger the drop twice. If you use an animation for the drop, then the second call would reset the platform for drop animation.

Let's see with coroutine since you started with that:

```
private bool m_dropPlatform;
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Player") && !m_dropPlatform)
    {
        m_dropPlatform = true;
        StartCoroutine(DropPlatformSequence());
    }
}

IEnumerator DropPlatformSequence()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
    myAnimationController.SetBool("FallWhenTouched", true);
}
```